# cucumber arity mismatch regex

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Hello everyone,

I have this step on feature file

```
When I log in with invalid credentials
```

and in the stepsDefinition class

```
@When("^I log in with (wrong|invalid) credentials$")
public void login(){
}
```

I want to use on my feature step with wrong or invalid word using regex but I get this error

```
 with pattern [^I log in with (.*) credentials$] is declared with 0 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 1 arguments [invalid]. Step: When I log in with invalid credentials at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.arityMismatch(StepDefinitionMatch.java:102) at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:60) at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37) at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39) at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44) at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
```

PS: I'm using cucumber-java and cucumber-junit 1.2.4 version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that this is a non-capturing group. Try this `(?:wrong|invalid)`. The '?:' part makes sure that cucumber does not pass it as an argument to the method.